# System Time Start Error in Google Earth Engine?

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, modis

I need extract date of each image and set to the id in each date by the below code. Although all elements in modis collection included `'system:time_start'` property, code returns error. Does anyone has any idea?

[image]

Code link: https://code.earthengine.google.com/a197f55e46e62099a53a9d47dc171f7e

```
Map.centerObject(geometry);

var modisData = function(img){
  var bands = img.select('su.*').multiply(0.0001);
  var date = ee.String(bands.date().format('YYYY-MM-dd'));
  return bands
  .copyProperties(img,img.propertyNames())
  .set('system:id', date)
  }

var modis = MOD09
.filterDate('2015','2020')
.filterBounds(geometry)
.map(modisData)


print(modis)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work with explicit casts:

```
 var date = ee.Algorithms.String(ee.Date(img.get('system:time_start')).format('YYYY-MM-dd'))
```

Not sure why your `.date()` approach is failing on MODIS though.

https://code.earthengine.google.com/f383b8171ad11bc8be6d7b11b040bd0d